# What is a term for finding a result?

Tags: single-word-requests

(Physics) experiments yield results, but I'm looking for a verb for the finding of a result.

"Find" seems to underestimate personal input in the experiment.
Other words like "Obtain" seem strange.

Is there a proper term?

Comment: Standard terminology in science papers is "We found that ..." & "The results obtained supported/contradicted ..." etc. Most science journals don't care about your personal input. They want their sentences in the impersonal active &, preferably, passive voice. In what kind of sentence do you want to use the personalized verb? Something like: "After we'd **bled, sweated, & cried a lot**, we finally created some publishable data for the tiresome & expensive experiments we had to run to write this paper"? What's wrong with the traditional way of saying things?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the word for "showing that something is meaningful"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113661/what-is-the-word-for-showing-that-something-is-meaningful)

Comment: Have a Eureka moment

Comment: In its present form this would be a NARQ because it is open-ended. Include an example sentence and sufficient context to avoid the post being closed.

Comment: We have [stringent standards](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) for single word requests. This question does not meet them. You may edit your question to fit those guidelines and it may be reopened then.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't *[discovered](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discover)* the word you are looking for?

> verb (used with object) 
>   1. to see, get knowledge of, learn of, find, or find out; gain sight or knowledge of (something previously unseen or unknown): to discover
>   America; to discover electricity.  Synonyms: detect, espy, descry,
>   discern, ascertain, unearth, ferret out, notice. 
>   2. to notice or realize: I discovered I didn't have my credit card with me when I went to pay my bill.
>   3. Archaic.  to make known; reveal; disclose.

Comment: We DETERMINED that the permittivity of space within the vacuum chamber varied between 8.8e-12 and 3.2e-10 farads per meter.

Answer (score 0):

*Ferret* would be close.

> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ferret?q=ferret)
>
> **verb** (ferrets, ferreting, ferreted)
>       **1** [no object] (of a person) hunt with ferrets, typically for rabbits:
>          (as noun **ferreting**)
>          *ferreting is increasing in popularity*
>           [with object] clear (a hole or area of ground) of rabbits with ferrets.
>       **2** [no object] rummage about in a place or container in search of something:
>          *he shambled over to the desk and ferreted around*
>           [with object] (**ferret something out**) discover information by means of an assiduous search or investigation:
>          *she had the ability to ferret out the facts*