# What is the word for "showing that something is meaningful"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I conduct an experiment and get results, and I can then relate those to real life in a way, what is the verb that this link to is doing?

My first thought was validate, but that isn't correct.

Comment: In biomedical literature, basic science results that can be used in the real world of medicine have _clinical implications_, ie, doctors can use them when treating disease. J.R.'s suggestion of   _applicable_ is a good one. Maybe "These findings **can be practically applied** in the energy industry to cut greenhouse gas emissions without requiring motorists to add another complicated & expensive exhaust filter to their vehicles".

Comment: You want an antonym for _floccinoccinihilipilification_.

Comment: We have [stringent standards](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) for single word requests. This question does not meet them. You may edit your question to fit those guidelines and it may be reopened then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems easier to come up with an adjective than a verb. My first thoughts were *relevant* and *pertinent* (as in, *“These results are relevant because...”*), but you're looking for a verb.

There's the verb *pertain*, which means (according to NOAD):

> **pertain**
>   (*intrans. verb*) be appropriate, related, or applicable

and also *apply*:

> **apply**
>   (*intrans. verb*) be applicable or relevant
>   (*trans. verb*) bring or put into operation or practical use : *the oil industry has failed to apply appropriate standards of care*.

So, you might say, *“We can apply these results to...”*

Answer (score -1):

signify?
That is the word you are after.

Comment: I'd like you to take a moment to compare your answer to J.R.'s and use his as a model to edit yours.